# Styling odd/even rows of a table differently

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have the following HTML:

```
<table id="price-table">
            <tr><th>Price</th><th>Value</th></tr>
            <tr class="price-row">
                <td>0</td>
                <td>1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr><th>Price</th><th>Value</th></tr>
            <tr class="price-row">
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to style every odd row with the class price-row using the following:

```css
#price-table tr.price-row:nth-child(odd) {
    color: green;
}
```

And every even row using:

```css
#price-table tr.price-row:nth-child(even) {
    color: blue;
}
```

However only the even rows are being styled, and the odd rows are being completely ignored. I don't understand why this is? Doesn't the first row have the id of 1 which would be styled as odd, and the second row have an id of 2 being styled as even?

I should mention that I do expect for this table to be expandable such that further rows are able to be added and correctly styled.

Very confused I have no idea what else to try, this doesn't seem complicated unless I'm making a very silly mistake.

Edit full HTML:

```html
<table id="price-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="price-row">
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="price-row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="price-row">
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="price-row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the selector in the `tr`, otherwise it only select the `tr` with that class, which are always even in your HTML structure

```css
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: green;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table id="price-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="price-row">
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="price-row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**UPDATE**  (based on op comment)

> Thank you for the reply, but my aim is to not style the rows containing "price value"

Use the sibling selector (`+` and `~`) then

```css
/* this will select every .price-row that has a TR as immediate previous sibling*/

tr+.price-row {
  background-color: green;
}


/*this will select every .price-row after the other .price-row */

.price-row~.price-row {
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<table id="price-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="price-row">
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="price-row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**UPDATE2**  (based on op comment)

> Thanks for the updated answer. However this only appears to style the first row after the first "price-row" row. After that no other odd rows which have the class "price-row" are styled as odd, only even?

You can use the `nth-child()` like below

```css
tr:nth-child(2n+2) {
  background: red
}


tr:nth-child(4n+2) {
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<table id="price-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="price-row">
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="price-row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="price-row">
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="price-row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="price-row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="price-row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but my aim is to not style the rows containing "price value".

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. However this only appears to style the first row after the first "price-row" row. After that no other odd rows which have the class "price-row" are styled as odd, only even?

Comment: html is the same apart from duplicating everything inside the table tag to test if your solution would scale in size. I have updated my question with the full html

Comment: @Vyres please see updated answer

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much.